# mongoDB - different query conditions based on number of results being returned

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, database, nosql

I have a document like this -

```
{
type: "One",
details: "This is one",
at: "some place, where one is relevant"
}
```

Other documents of similar schema can have the same 'type' with different 'details', 'at', etc.
There can be several 'type's.

Now, I want to write a query to return me a certain number (upper limit, say 5) of documents matching certain 'type's (which I can do using `limit` and `$in`) which can omit the 'type' criteria if the results contain less than 5 documents.

For e.g., if I allow only 'One' and 'Two' as 'type' and I use a limit of 5, then if the number of results is less than 5 (say, 2), it should return me those documents that had 'One' and 'Two' as their types (i.e. 2 documents) and 3 more documents without looking at their 'type'.

I hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't like to use script  the option I can see is  using `aggregate` with introducing extra field `weight` for instance to move up matching documents and then sort  by  `weight` and limit total results:

```
db.test.aggregate({ 
  $project: {
    type: 1, 
    details: 1, 
    at: 1, 
    weight: { 
      $cond: [ 
        { "$or": [  
          {$eq: ["$type", "One"] }, 
          {$eq: ["$type", "Two"] } 
        ] }, 
      0, 1] } 
    } },  
    {$sort: {weight: 1}},
    { $limit : 5 }
);
```

Notes about this example. I replace $in with several equals in $or for simplicity. If you don't like to have `weight` in final result you can remove it by applying another projection in aggregation pipeline.

Test db:

```
> db.test.find({})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58067329a7518db4d3d2e973"), "type" : "One", "details" : "This is one", "at" : "some place, where one is relevant" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5806733da7518db4d3d2e974"), "type" : "Two", "details" : "This is two", "at" : "some place, where one is relevant" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5806734ba7518db4d3d2e975"), "type" : "Three", "details" : "This is three", "at" : "some place, where one is relevant" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58067374a7518db4d3d2e976"), "type" : "Four", "details" : "This is four", "at" : "some place, where one is relevant" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58067381a7518db4d3d2e977"), "type" : "Five", "details" : "This is five", "at" : "some place, where one is relevant" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5806738fa7518db4d3d2e978"), "type" : "Six", "details" : "This is six", "at" : "some place, where one is relevant" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("580673cfa7518db4d3d2e979"), "type" : "Seven", "details" : "This is seven", "at" : "some place, where one is relevant" }
```

Result:

```
> db.test.aggregate({ $project: { type: 1, details: 1, at: 1, weight: { $cond: [ { "$or": [  {$eq: ["$type", "One"] }, {$eq: ["$type", "Two"] } ] }, 0, 1] } } },  {$sort: {weight: 1}}, { $limit : 5 }, {$project: {type: 1, details: 1, at: 1} });
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58067329a7518db4d3d2e973"), "type" : "One", "details" : "This is one", "at" : "some place, where one is relevant" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5806733da7518db4d3d2e974"), "type" : "Two", "details" : "This is two", "at" : "some place, where one is relevant" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58067374a7518db4d3d2e976"), "type" : "Four", "details" : "This is four", "at" : "some place, where one is relevant" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58067381a7518db4d3d2e977"), "type" : "Five", "details" : "This is five", "at" : "some place, where one is relevant" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5806734ba7518db4d3d2e975"), "type" : "Three", "details" : "This is three", "at" : "some place, where one is relevant" }
```

Comment: Perfect @mike-shauneu ! Works perfectly!
I can't help notice that in the example we have only two possible weights - which I'm assuming one is for condition matched (so, 0) and not matched (so, 1) and then it sorts by weight.
But can we have more weights?

I think that should be appending to the $cond array - both the condition and an additional weight value. Is it so?

Comment: Because we need to  include in result  documents that matched and not matched condition and we need to  make  sure that we are starting from  matching  docs we  introduce weight and sort  by  it  to  push  matched  docs up.